# What is the simplest way to implement data encryption for Raspberry PI project that communicate through Bluetooth?

Tags: encryption, perfect-secrecy, lightweight

I have developed a project based on Raspberry Pi that communicates through Bluetooth with Android application, My idea is to enhance its privacy through encryption. So, I've tried `chaotic encryption`.

But I've observed a higher lattency while encrypting & Mainly I was dealing with images..It is adding up a lot of noise in channel and resulting in destroying the contents of the image(Most of the times) after decrypting.

I was wondering is there is any lightweight encryption methodology for my case?